# Text field attributes in layered navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, filter, search, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm currently setting up a Magento for some friend of mine that sells wines.
He would like to have a quick search somewhere where he can filter out all wines by grape or wine house or region or country. Unfortunately you can't filter wines in layered navigation by text fields. Or can I somehow.

I would really appreciate any help on this guys!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work):

> In order for an attribute to appear as a layered navigation filter, the Catalog Input Type for Store Owner must be Dropdown, Multiple Select, or Price

That means you can't filter by a textarea type attribute out of the box in Magento.

Answer (score 3):

(sorry cant comment on the above as don't have enough points on here yet)

You should create 4 new attributes:

grape
wine house
region
Country

These can be attribute type dropdown, you can then add a number of values against each attribute for example:

Region - Bordeaux, Normandy etc

When you wish to add a new attribute value you will need to do this from within the attribute and then select it from the edit/create product page.